# How to set margins for two different SVG Polygon shape

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have design two different polygon shape with image, but the problem is I am not able to set their position like margin-left or margin-top, in mozilla both shapes are coming but in chrome and opera only single shape is coming. as well as I am also not able to make mouseover

below are my code for 2 SVG

```
<style>
#box1{
height: 0px;
width: 220px;
padding: 10px;
border: 5px solid gray;
margin: 0px; 
}
#box2{
height: 0px;
width: 0px;
}
#img {clip-path: url(#clipping);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipping);
  -webkit-shape-outside: url(#clipping);
   shape-outside: url(#clipping);
}
#img2 {clip-path: url(#clipping);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipping);
  -webkit-shape-outside: url(#clipping);
   shape-outside: url(#clipping);
}
</style>
<div id="box1">
<svg width="0" height="0" >
  <defs>
   <clipPath id="clipping">
<!--      <circle cx="284" cy="213" r="213" />-->
    <path d="M188 0 L1 0 L1 188 L188 0 Z">
   </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div id="img">
<img src="img/1.jpg" width="568">
</div>
</div>

<div id="box2">
<svg width="0" height="0" >
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping2">
<!--      <circle cx="284" cy="213" r="213" />-->
        <path d="M181 0 L181 149 L1 149 L181 0 Z">
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div id="img2">
<img src="img/2.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean to use clipping2 with img2?

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, actually I am already using img2 with clipping2, In the above code there are to SVG Polygon Shape, I am able to set margin in Mozilla but not in Chrome or Opera, Like margin-top, margin-left. how to do that?

Comment: No, not now, I have not mention in my code. I am doing this in browser with inspect element. @RobertLongson

Comment: @RobertLongson See i have added CSS for Box1 and Box2 in style tag, now I want to give margin-left to #box2, here in the above code, Contents on #box1 are not coming within the box, how to fix the contents within the box1 and box2